# Use custom UserCreationForm with GeoDjango admin (OSMGeoAdmin)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, geodjango

```
Django==2.2.1
GDAL==2.3.2
django-username-email==2.2.4
```

I have a simple Django application with a custom user model based on [django-username-email](https://pypi.org/project/django-username-email/)'s `AbstractCUser`, which removes the `username` from the user model, using e-mail address instead. On the user model, I defined a `PointField` field storing the user's current location.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
from cuser.models import AbstractCUser

class User(AbstractCUser):
    """Custom user model that extends AbstractCUser."""

    current_location = gis_models.PointField(null=True, blank=True,)
```

I would like to register this model in Django admin so that I can register new users and view/set their location with a map widget. This kind of works if I use a custom user admin based on `admin.OSMGeoAdmin` in combination with a custom user change form:

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm

class CustomUserAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    model = get_user_model()
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm    # <- there seems to be a problem here
    form = CustomUserChangeForm

    list_display = ['email', 'last_name', 'first_name']
    readonly_fields = ['last_login', 'date_joined']


admin.site.register(get_user_model(), CustomUserAdmin)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm    

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()
        exclude = ('username',)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'current_location',
            # ...
        )
```

When I open an existing user record in the Django admin, the required fields are displayed as intended, and the current location is displayed on a map. However, the same form seems to be used for user creation as well (i.e. `add_form` has no effect), which makes it impossible to add new users via the admin, because the password setting functionality is not embedded correctly (see screen shot). [image: django admin]

The problem seems to be that `OSMGeoAdmin`[inherits from ModelAdmin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/admin/options.py), which in contrast to the standard `UserAdmin`does not have an `add_form` property.

Is there any way to specify a custom user creation form in this case (ideally the `UserCreationForm` provided by `django-username-email` while maintaining the ability to display point fields on a map on the user change form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `get_form` similar to how `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin` does.

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Use special form during user creation
    """
    defaults = {}
    if obj is None:
        defaults['form'] = self.add_form
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    return super().get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following schillingt's suggestion, this is the code I ended up using:

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from cuser.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import CustomUserChangeForm


class CustomUserAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    model = get_user_model()
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm

    list_display = ['email', 'last_name', 'first_name']
    readonly_fields = ['last_login', 'date_joined']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Use special form during user creation.

        Override get_form method in the same manner as django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin does.
        """
        defaults = {}
        if obj is None:
            defaults['form'] = self.add_form
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **defaults)


admin.site.register(get_user_model(), CustomUserAdmin)
```